# Using Microsoft's Spellcheck Bing API with WPF, returning zero spelling mistakes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, api, xaml

I am attempting to use Microsoft's Bing Spellcheck API with a WPF application.  I have a textbox where I enter in some text, and then a button that checks the spelling in the textbox, and should return the red line underneath anything that is misspelled.  I think I have it programmed correctly, but nothing is happening when I click on the button.  I am following along with Microsoft's code snippet on how to do this: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56e73033cf5ff80c2008c679/operations/57855119bca1df1c647bc358

I understand that WPF does have a Spellcheck feature available, however I want to practice using some of Microsoft's Cognitive APIs for my own benefit.

Here is my code for my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` of the WPF application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace Project1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    static async void MakeRequest()
    {
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

        //Request headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "e94333d69eb6493d86aaa4b25e42d0d0");

        //Request parameters
        queryString["text"] = window.TextBox.Text;

        var uri = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?" + queryString;

        await client.GetAsync(uri);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MakeRequest();
    }
}
}
```

If anyone is able to help me understand what I am doing wrong, that would be great.  I am completely new to using APIs so I am still trying to figure out exactly how to use them.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the result of your request when you debug?

Comment: You also have to specify the `mode` in the `queryString`

Comment: How exactly do I check the result of my request when I debug?  I've set breakpoints before and it does play through the entire method, but I'm unsure on how to check what the result of the request is with Visual Studio, since I've never done GET requests such as this before.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that u don't know how to get the result I will show u an example.
You have to parse the reponse and update your `TextBox` by yourself.

```
static async void DownloadPage()
    {
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        queryString["text"] = "Bill Gatas";
        queryString["mode"] = "spell";
        var uri = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?" + queryString;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "e94333d69eb6493d86aaa4b25e42d0d0");

            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(uri))
            {
                string result = await response .Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //Put here a breakpoint
            }
        }
    }
```

If you put a breakpoint on `result` you will see that it contains the response (with suggestions) in `JSON` format.

Comment: Interesting, so when I run the program it does say that I have a required parameter missing, and that parameter is the "text" parameter (from queryString).  Can I not use `window.TextBox.text` as my text parameter then?  It doesn't make sense why I wouldn't be able to use that.

Comment: You can use `window.TextBox.Text` instread of `Bill Gatas`, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Alright, then I wonder why it still says that I have the "text" parameter missing?

Comment: I don't know if you made any modifications but my sample is working, I tested it